# Logical OR of multiple Optional instances?

Tags: java, java-stream, option-type

Is there a more elegant way to represent the following algorithm using the Java core API?

```
Optional<Float> input = Optional.of(A);
Optional<Float> output = input.map(function1).map(function2);
if (!output.isPresent())
{
  output = input.map(function1).map(function2);
  if (!output.isPresent())
  {
    output = input.map(function3).map(function4);
      if (!output.isPresent())
        output = input.map(function5).map(function6);
  }
}
```

That is, instead of nesting multiple invocations of `isPresent()` I'd like to invoke a method like `map()` but that would only get invoked if a value is absent.

In an ideal world, I want to invoke something along the lines of:

```
Optional<Float> output = input.or(input.map(function1).map(function2), input.map(function2).map(function3), input.map(function4).map(function5));
```

This is what I've got so far, but can we do better?

```
public class Optionals
{
    /**
     * @param <T>       the type of value returned by the Optionals
     * @param suppliers one or more suppliers that return a supplier
     * @return the first Optional that {@link Optional#isPresent() isPresent()}
     */
    public static <T> Optional<T> or(Supplier<Optional<T>>... suppliers)
    {
        for (Supplier<Optional<T>> supplier: suppliers)
        {
            Optional<T> candidate = supplier.get();
            if (candidate.isPresent())
                return candidate;
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    /**
     * Prevent construction.
     */
    private Optionals()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I would rename your `or` function to `firstOf` and just use it. Seems to me like a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like the `Supplier` scheme to much in this case and would probably prefer this approach:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Float x = 1.0f;
    final Optional<Float> input = Optional.of(x);
    Optional<Float> output = firstPresent(input, (a) -> a.map(FUNCTION1).map(FUNCTION2),
                                     (a) -> a.map(FUNCTION3).map(FUNCTION4),
                                     (a) -> a.map(FUNCTION5).map(FUNCTION6));
}

@SafeVarargs
public static <I,O> Optional<O> firstPresent(Optional<I> input, Function<Optional<I>, Optional<O>>... functions) {
    for (Function<Optional<I>, Optional<O>> function : functions) {
        final Optional<O> output = function.apply(input);
        if(output.isPresent()) {
            return output;
        }
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

Comment: In my case the `Supplier` captures `input` from the outer code block, but yes this is more explicit.

Comment: @Gili this way you can also reuse the lambdas/functions more easily. The suppliers need to be constructed for each input.

Comment: I don't really reuse lambdas/functions, but that's a good point. Who knows what I might need in the future...

Answer (score 2):

`Optional` has an `orElse` method; if you call this, it will return the value in the `Optional` if it is not empty, or the value that you pass to `orElse` if it is empty.

So you could use nested `orElse` calls, like this:

```
Float output = input.map(function1).map(function2)
    .orElse(input.map(function3).map(function4)
        .orElse(input.map(function5).map(function6)
            .orElse(0.0f)));
```

Note that the end result is in this case not an `Optional<Float>` but a `Float`. If you don't want a default return value such as `0.0f` when none of the mappings returned a value, you could for example make it throw an exception:

```
Float output = input.map(function1).map(function2)
    .orElse(input.map(function3).map(function4)
        .orElse(input.map(function5).map(function6)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("No result"))));
```

Comment: Wouldn't this lead to always evaluating function3 to function6?

Comment: @TheConstructor you can use [orElseGet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) to pass a lambda instead and avoid eager evaluation.

Comment: This doesn't work for me because it returns `T` instead of `Optional<T>`. I have 3 ways to look up the value, but it's possible that all 3 will return an empty value.

Answer (score 1):

```
return Arrays.stream(suppliers).filter(supplier -> supplier.get().isPresent()).toArray();
```

Comment: did not test this. java 8 lambdas using array streams.

Comment: This will evaluate all suppliers, which is not what I want. I want to return to evaluate the suppliers in order and stop as soon as one of them returns a non-empty value.

Comment: `Arrays.stream(suppliers).map(Supplier::get).filter(Optional::isPresent).findFirst().orElse(Optional::empty)`

Answer (score 0):

A way to implement 'multiple condition' logical AND by Java8 predicates (by Yosi Lev):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 Optional<String> stringOptional = Optional.of( "this is a string" );
 Predicate<String> isNotNull  = s-> s != null;
 Predicate<String> isSizeGT0  = s-> s.length() > 0 ;
 Predicate<String> isSizeGT20 = s-> s.length() > 20 ;
 // calling isOk() with all required Predicates to be approved:
 System.out.println(isOk(stringOptional, isNotNull, isSizeGT0, isSizeGT20));
}//main()

@SafeVarargs
private static <I> boolean isOk(Optional<I> inp, Predicate<I>... predicates){
 // Enforce all predicates on input..
 boolean b = Arrays.stream( predicates ).allMatch( pr->pr.test( inp.get()));
 return b; 
}
```